# 'instance failure' error while connection string is correct

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have following code on page load event:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=14GRAFICALI\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sagar;Integrated Security=True")
        '-----------------------fill name ddl------------------------------'

        Try

            da = New SqlDataAdapter("select EmpName from empMaster_VB", con)
            ds = New DataSet()
            da.Fill(ds)
            For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count

                ddlName.Items.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString())

            Next


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        '--------------------------------------------------------------------'


        '----------------fill expence-------------------------------------'

        Try

            da = New SqlDataAdapter("select ExpName from expenceType_VB", con)
            ds = New DataSet()
            da.Fill(ds)
            For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count

                ddlExpence.Items.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString())

            Next


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


        '---------------------------------------------------------------'



    End Sub
```

This code is to fill drop downs with names and expence values in database tables.

I am getting '`instance failure`' error while executing the code.

I checked one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830824/instance-failure-in-asp-net?answertab=votes#tab-top) on stack and checked my connection string. But, my connection string is also correct.

Please help me if anything else is missing in this code.

Comment: Are you opening the connection?

Comment: no, i am not opening the connection

Comment: add `con.Open()` before you do the Select statement

Comment: i removed // from datasource and made / and it worked.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

As you got the error "instance failure", that might be the error with your SQL Server instance..

Make sure your SQL Server instance(MSSQLSERVER) is running, where you can check in: Services list. TO get into services list: open run dialog box and type: "services.msc" (without quotes) and hit Enter. That takes you to services management console, where you can check whether your instance in running or not..

If the problem still persists, then try using: Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS instead.. :)

Happy Coding... :)

Comment: Try restarting your instance once.. :)

Comment: That could even work for .\SQLEXPRESS if the machine is local... :)

Comment: yup, // was issue. it worked on both, only i was not removing // and making it / . Thanks

Comment: Perfect solution. My connectionString previously was "Server=OWNER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS" and got Instance Failure after using EF6's update-database command. After changing it to "Data Source=.\SLQEXPRESS" all works great.

Comment: I was using environment variable to register the connection string. So following doesn't work: `Data Source=localhost\\MyInstanceName`. You don't have to escape \ when using environment variables. So using  `Data Source=localhost\MyInstanceName` solved the issue.

Comment: My issue also resolved by just changing connection string to .\SQLEXPRESS

Answer (score 49):

I have the following connection:

```
Data Source=MyComputerName\SQL2012ENTERPRS;Initial Catalog=RESTFUL; User Id=myuser; Password=mypass123;
```

My server's identifier is: `MyComputerName\SQL2012ENTERPRS`

But since I'm use a string, I add another blackslash `\` so the string becomes:

```
public string connectionString = "Data Source=DAFWKN409C67Q\\SQL2012ENTERPRS;Initial Catalog=RESTFUL; User Id=rest_user; Password=rest_pwd_01;";
```

I have forgotten that I must remove one of `\` since I am not use the default string block, I use an XML file to save my connection string and then everything is okay so my suspicion is that your instance name is not correct.

This is my connection string it I use on a local pc using SQL
Express:

```
string servername = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Workshop;Integrated Security=True";
```

You should modify the above string with your server name and instance name and ensure it is correct.

Comment: Was having issue with NLog and database target and this solved!

Comment: I was having the same problem and this answer worked for me, I removed the double \\ in the data source name to a single \

Comment: I was also having the same issue and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 29):

I had this issue because I got the connection string from `appsettings.Development.json`:

```
"Server=msi\\DataBaseName;Database=Super25;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

but when I changed to

```
"Data Source=msi\DataBaseName;Initial Catalog=Super25;Integrated Security=True;"
```

solved!

Answer (score 28):

in my case just kick up the double \\ to one slush \ 
:=)

Comment: I didn't update my exe configuration file and some how this got updated with two back slashes.  I checked my source control and it was a single slash up until this started happening. You were right on the money; thanks.

Comment: this worked for me, many time in c# code we pur @ then there is no need of \\ just use \ if @ is preceding the connection string.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Two slashes were fine in ASP.NET Core project, but crashed in plain ASP.NET.

Answer (score 11):

[image: I shared an image for figure out the issue on my EF Core 3.0 in a Separate Class Library.]
The root cause is Regular literal ("Backslash: \") and Verbatim literal ("@"Backslash: \"") .
Reference https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Strings

Answer (score 5):

Use the wildcard "@" before "Data Source" declaration. someting like this: 
connetionString = @"Data Source=...

So you'll be able to use only a back slash. Like this: @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\jcabarros...

Answer (score 2):

Your answer lies in the connected services. edit provider and select the three dots once you find your database select advanced in the advanced you will see your connection string which looks like below.

Data Source=Server\ServerInstance;Initial Catalog=yourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True

You can add more services and configure more there.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but perhaps a good update. I couldn't find a good answer on the web search.

I got the same 'Instance Failed' error when trying to reference a DbContext from another project in the same solution. The 1st project had a DbContext and the connection string, and the 2nd project in the solution was trying to reference it. The 1st app ran ok on its own, issue only occurred when running the 2nd app.

The issue was that the app.config file that had the connection string from the 1st project was not in view/scope of the 2nd project. So the connection string wasn't assembled.

My solution was to copy the app.config from the first project to the second project.

This was on VS 2019.

Hope this helps