# Error in adding ConnectionString in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

I am getting error in adding ConnectionString from Database.
Can you please guide me?
[image]

Comment: You have to escape the \

Comment: `VRO75JO\\KAMI123`

Comment: Thank you for you help sir. I have applied it and removes this error. Bu now, some different error has occured...

Instance Failure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the connection string should be something like,

`"Data Source=DESKTOP-VRO75JO\\KAMI123..."`

or

`@"Data Source=DESKTOP-VRO75JO\KAMI123..."`

Please do refer

MSDN Link | [Escape Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for you help sir. I have applied it and removes this error. Bu now, some different error has occurred...

Instance Failure

Answer (score 1):

Change your connection's data source from `DESKTOP-VRO75JO\KAMI123` into `DESKTOP-VRO75JO\\KAMI123`

Comment: Thank you for you help sir. I have applied it and removes this error. Bu now, some different error has occured...
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-VRO75JO\\KAMI123;Initial Catalog=Phone;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
Instance Failure

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650482/instance-failure-error-while-connection-string-is-correct