# C# SystemInvalidOperationException(instance error)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I connected server I have error in `adapter.fill(dt)` line

```cs
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from musteriii",a);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I am learning how can I use SqlDataAdapter but I have a problem please help me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the rules on how to ask a good question: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular: Describe exactly what you want to achieve, what you did and what errors (exceptions or similar) you got under what conditions these errors occur.

Comment: Does ['instance failure' error while connection string is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650482/instance-failure-error-while-connection-string-is-correct) help?

Comment: Are you sure that the `SqlConnection` was already open before entering this block of code? These errors are typically thrown at connection open time because there's something incorrect about the properties in the connection string.

Comment: SqlConnection a = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-*******\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SQLFULL;Integrated Security=True");  I wrote this line and my sqql connection property true

Comment: I restarted sql server services but fail already continue

Comment: When using verbatim strings, `@"..."`, you don't need to escape your backslashes. Have you tried using just a single backslash here? Ref: [Verbatim text - @ in variables, attributes, and string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim).

Comment: Please give debugging details, see [ask].

Comment: @AlwaysLearning The [`DbDataAdapter.Fill Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill) does need an open connection. It will take care of that itself.

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewMorton, I'm aware of that. I was challenging Op's assertion that they had already established the SQL Server connection because the exception message was indicating otherwise.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Of course, I missed out the vital "not", as in "does not", in that comment. Oops.

Comment: @tahaGlbz If the database is on the same machine as the program, then `@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SQLFULL;Integrated Security=True"` is more likely to work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this?
`SqlConnection a = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-*******\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SQLFULL;Integrated Security=True");`

And is your SQLConnection open?