# How Can I Fix Instance Failure Using SQL Database In C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm doing a login form following this video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcmmCcMs8yU

This is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Hp\\Documents\\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("'Select Count (*) From Login Where Username='" + textBox1.Text + "'and Password='" + textBox2.Text + "''" ,con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows[1][1].ToString() == "1")
    {
        this.Hide();
        Main ss = new Main();
        ss.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Good");
    }
}
```

My problem is on the `sda.Fill(dt)` line, where it tells me I have an Instance Failure.

What can I do to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At which time in linked video we can see complete error message?

Comment: It isn't shown in the video, I checked it a thousand times and it's not running well :(.

Comment: In C# indexes start with 0. It should be `dt.Rows[0][0]`. BTW I would suggest a) using `.ExecuteScalar` and b) reading on SQL Injection and parametrized queries

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: You mix a literal string and escape chars in your connection string. Try using .\SQLEXPRESS instead of .\\SQLEXPRESS. I think you also need to have sqlserver-express installed since you need an instance to actually attach your mdf file to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the correct connection string?

Did you try to remove the double-slash between the server name and the database instance name in the connection string?

This from your code:  `.\\SQLEXPRESS`

To be this: `.\SQLEXPRESS`

Check this: [Instance Failure in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830824/instance-failure-in-asp-net?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Really it should remove the `@` from `@"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\.....`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have three problems:

First: when you start your connection string with `@`, you shouldn't escape backslashes with backslashes. Either remove the `@`, or remove the **all** double backslashes.

Your other problem is that your SQL query is wrapped in single-quotes:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("'Select Count (*) From Login Where Username='" + textBox1.Text + "'and Password='" + textBox2.Text + "''" ,con);
```

This should work:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From Login Where Username='" + textBox1.Text + "'and Password='" + textBox2.Text + "'" ,con);
```

Your third problem is that you are vulnerable to SQL-injection. That's not keeping your solution from working, but it is extremely bad practise. Never use user input directly in SQL queries, use a parameterized query, see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements).

**Edit**

As @bradbury9 points out `dt.Rows[1][1]` would throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. There is only one row, so it should be `dt.Rows[0][whichever_zero_based_column_you_are_interested_in]`.